# UISwitch always returns "False" value even when Switch is on

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

Every time I switch the UISwitch to either on or off in the simulator, it still returns false even when one of the switches is on. I even tried adding

```
self.switch1.on = true;
```

inside the if statement of checkSwitch1Changed.

This is my code in .m file.

```
- (IBAction)checkSwitch1Changed:(id)sender {

    if (self.switch1.on)
    {
        self.switch2.on = NO;
        self.switch3.on = NO;
        self.switch4.on = NO;
    }
    ...
}


- (IBAction)checkSwitch2Changed:(id)sender {

    if (self.switch2.on) 
    {
        self.switch1.on = NO; 
        self.switch3.on = NO; 
        self.switch4.on = NO;
    }
    ...
}
- (IBAction)checkSwitch3Changed:(id)sender {

    if (self.switch3.on)
    {
        self.switch1.on = NO;
        self.switch2.on = NO;
        self.switch4.on = NO;
    }
    ...
}


- (IBAction)checkSwitch4Changed:(id)sender {

    if (self.switch4.on) 
    {
        self.switch1.on = NO;
        self.switch2.on = NO;
        self.switch3.on = NO;
    }
    ...
}
```

This is my code in .h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *switch1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *switch2;
- (IBAction)checkSwitch1Changed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)checkSwitch2Changed:(id)sender;
//********

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *switch3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *switch4;
- (IBAction)checkSwitch3Changed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)checkSwitch4Changed:(id)sender;
```

This actually works and sends back true if I send the data using that view controller. But I am trying to access this data from another view controller and it sends back false. I used this code to access the data from the other view controller.

```
//import data from SetupController'
SetupController *setupController = [[SetupController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"SetupController" bundle:nil];
...
    Firebase *postRef = [savedRef childByAppendingPath: @"Switches"];
NSDictionary *post1 = @{
@"Check1": @(setupController.self.switch1.on),
```

Comment: Are you sure that `self.switch1` isn't `nil`?

Comment: How do I check that? I have the switch connected to a database and every time I request the switches status in my firebase database it always returns false. @rmaddy

Comment: are all of your IBAction's getting called when one switch is turned on?  you named it checkSwitch1Changed so with that naming scheme when you turn switch2 on and switch1 is turned off, checkSwitch1Changed, checkSwitch3Changed, etc. should be called.... right?

Comment: No they are all individual. I just updated the code to clarify it a bit more. @MSU_Bulldog

Comment: have you tried turning it on/off, by calling setOn:animated? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISwitch/setOn:animated:  isOn is a custom setter property that you need to call to set the switch on or off

Comment: isn't the getter of "on" property named "isOn"??

Comment: your brackets are wrong.. is it just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try checking for the `isOn` property, instead of `on`?

```
if (self.switch1.on)
```

becomes

```
if (self.switch1.isOn)
```

Also check that the IBAction associated with the switch is a

```
ValueChanged
```

event, and that the reference outlets are properly linked.

Comment: I did and that still returns false even when the switch is on

Comment: I have Value Changed linked to each individual IBAction on storyboard. I did see your edit but I had it like that before and it still didn't work. I just need the UISwitch to return 'true' when I flip the switch if that makes sense.

Comment: I added another edit at the bottom of my post if you could please check it out.

Comment: @CarlosAlan i read the edit, and i think the problem is that the viewcontroller is just instantiated. You should check your design.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to also 'set' the switch to on, rather than *listening* to see if it's on (without setting first, if that makes sense).

I'm sure there's a much more elegant way of doing this (it's a but long winded here), but you should get the idea and this method should work if you hook **ALL** the switches up to the **one** `IBAction` and changed the `sender` on the method from `id` to `UISwitch`.

*(of course you don't need to use just the **one** IBAction, though it makes more sense if you do, as opposed to 4 actions all wanting to do the same thing)*

```
- (IBAction)switchPressed:(UISwitch *)sender {

       if (sender==self.switch1) {
           self.switch1.on = YES;
           self.switch2.on = NO;
           self.switch3.on = NO;
           self.switch4.on = NO;
       }
    if (sender==self.switch2) {
            self.switch1.on = NO;
            self.switch2.on = YES;
            self.switch3.on = NO;
            self.switch4.on = NO;
        }
    if (sender==self.switch3) {
            self.switch1.on = NO;
            self.switch2.on = NO;
            self.switch3.on = YES;
            self.switch4.on = NO;
        }
    if (sender==self.switch4) {
             self.switch1.on = NO;
             self.switch2.on = NO;
             self.switch3.on = NO;
             self.switch4.on = YES;
         }

}
```

Comment: I tried this and linked them all up to one IBAction which was a good idea but it still returns as false when I ask for the value of self.switch1.on or any other when I physically have them on in the simulator.

Comment: @CarlosAlan, Just realised my code is wrong here, missed the .on after the switch name. I'll update answer

Comment: This actually works and sends back true if I send the data using that view controller. But I am trying to access this data from another view controller and it sends back false. I used this code to access the data from the other view controller.
 //import data from SetupController'
        SetupController *setupController = [[SetupController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SetupController" bundle:nil];